# SQL Server Select Distinct Returns Different results each time

Tags: sql, sql-server

Now, I'm more of a Dev than a DBA, but this doesn't seem to be very logical, so putting aside whether or not there is a better way of doing this, I'm struggling to find the logic in this.

select distinct testid from tbl_result

A seeming simple piece of sql, right, the trouble is that when I run it (both in code and query analyser) I get different result sets each time. what is interesting is that the result sets return the same number of records, and they are unique against the other (no value shows up in both datasets) but after a random number of F5 pushes we get different results, there isn't even any consistent number of times that each different set shows.

Table structure:

- 12 columns, mostly ints, one varchar(50)
- It has an identity column as primary key, so is clustered index
- There are over 500,000 records in the table

As I said to start, I know I can get the list of 1000 or so testIds a different way, but I'm really curious if anyone has come across this kind of scenario before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's just that the rows are being returned in a different *order*, that is entirely expected. SQL offers no guarantees on the *order* in which it returns results, outside of any explicit requirements that you've provided to it via an `ORDER BY` clause - no `ORDER BY`, no guarantees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possibly returning the same testid values, just in a different order? Can you give more information about the table structure? Is there a clustered index and/or primary key on the table? Why specifically are you selecting DISTINCT instead of just selecting the testids? Have you taken a look at the execution plan?

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, it was just a rapid-fire list of all the things I'd consider first, or that might help us troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: 1 - it is different results as I tried to explain, but difficult to explain.
2 - I explained the table structure above - it is clustered, and does have a primary (identity column)
3 - As I said, I do know how to get the distinct list of Ids from a different table, but that doesn't solve this problem
4 - yep we've run the execution plan, always the same.

Dude, it's doing my head in, it's just not logical :)

Comment: yeah now worries about all the questions, they are good ones :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, (non)issue solved, the problem was somewhere between keyboard and chair, so humble pie time!
 
A customer swore to me that the lookup values that I was displaying in a dropdownlist in a web front end would randomly give two different lists. Sure enough, when the page loaded, sometimes you'd get one list, other times you'd get a different list, always either one or the other and they appeared to be in order, I'd check the first 20 or so and the last 20 or so out of a list of a couple of hundred. Continued.....

Comment: Since the error was reported top down I tried to solve it top down so, so I checked the code, I could see the lambda statement I'd written was distinct and ordered and was running every time the page loaded, it didn't really make sense. I profiled the database and confirmed that every time the page loaded, the same piece of sql would run, the key was that the order by clause wasn't flowing through from my lambda into sql, I should have solved it there! But... as I'd checked the list and seen it appeared to be in order top and bottom I hate saying this but I assumed it was ordered.Continued....

Comment: I then took the profiled piece of sql and ran it in query analyzer, the same random thing was returing - what looked like two very different lists that appeared to be in order (first 20 or so records a,b,c.... last 20 or so ....x, y, z).
What actually was happening was that sql was returning all of the records, but without an order by clause it seems to retrieve the data in two lists, then join them together, so I actually had and a-z+a-z, I was always looking at the first couple and the last couple and they appeared to be in order. Continued.....

Comment: If I'd viewed the middle of the list I'd have very quickly seen where A + Z met in the middle, what made them look different was that sometimes list A was on top, other times list B was on top, hence it appeared like it was two  very diffent lists.

To summarize - after getting very caught up trying to solve a complicated issue that didn't look logical, I was missing the fact that it was a very simple issue with a solution that I'd discounted through an assumption - I felt very stupid!!